# Integeration with one end infinite

Tags: calculus, integration

Part1:For any natural number $n$ prove that $\int_0^1 \cos(nx)ln(x)dx$ exists and is finite.

Part2: Show that the above expression when n tends to inf is zero.

I have a proof for first part but I am not sure I just triangle inequality and the fact the the absolute value of cos is never more that 1 as follows:

$|\int_0^1 \cos(nx)ln(x)dx|\le\int_0^1 |\cos(nx)||ln(x)|dx \le \int_0^1 |ln(x)|$

But ln is always negative in that interval so we can easily show that the R.H.S is 1 so the left hand side shoud diverge.I don't know if this is completely ok.For the second part our master gave a hint that we should split the integeration interval into to intervals $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ and $[\frac{1}{n},1]$ then the integral in the first part is easy to prove that it tends to zero when n tends to infinite but the second interval is hard to get conclusion any hints?

Answer (score 1):

This is just an attempt{and too long for a comment, hence posting it as an answer}. If the way I have done this is right, then we can see that the summation converges as k tends to $\infty$. However I haven't been able to prove the same when it's multiplied by $n^k$, but I hope this helps you and you figure it out from here.

If you do, kindly do share your further steps.

$$\int_0^1 \cos(nx)\ln(x)dx$$
Let us represent $\cos nx$ in terms of it's Taylor expansion.
Therefore,
$$\cos(nx) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k n^{2k} x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

Thus, $\int_0^1\cos (nx)\ln(x) $becomes
$$\int_0^1\ln(x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k n^{2k}x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k n^k}{(2k)!} \int_0^1 x^{2k} \log(x) dx$$

Applying$\int UV=U\int V -\int U'\int V $
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k n^k}{(2k)!} \Bigl(\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1} \log(x)-\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)^2}\Bigr)_0^1$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k n^k}{(2k)!} \Bigl(\frac{-1}{(2k+1)^2}\Bigr)$$

If we didn't have the $n^k$ term here, it's very obvious that this series converges. Since we do, I'm not sure of it's impact on the summation...